# iOS: Passing data(array value or string) between views?

Tags: ios

how can I pass NSString value to "webwhatsnew" subview using below code . Thanks

```
-(IBAction)Whatsnew {
  NSString *myString =[URL absoluteString]; 
  // how can I pass this value to "webwhatsnew" subview 
  webwhatsnew = [[WebWhatsnewView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebWhatsnewView"bundle:nil]; 
  [self.view addSubview:webwhatsnew.view];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an NSString property in WebWhatsnewView. Then just set a value to it. Example:

```
//WebWhatsnewView.h
...
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someString;
...

-(IBAction)Whatsnew {
  NSString *myString =[URL absoluteString]; 
  webwhatsnew = [[WebWhatsnewView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebWhatsnewView"bundle:nil]; 
  webwhatsnew.someString = myString; //if myString is a string that you want to pass
  [self.view addSubview:webwhatsnew.view];
}
```

Hope it helps

**EDIT**

```
//WebWhatsnewView.m
...
@synthesize someString;
...
```

Comment: Thanks Novarg.No hope above code is not working ..pls verify my screen shot .http://www.flickr.com/photos/ambitionbag/7073069907/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: @JoshyJoseph did you also synthesize it in the .m file?

Comment: I already added @synthesize someString; in WebWhatsnewView.m but same issue http://www.flickr.com/photos/ambitionbag/7073069907/in/photostream/lightbox/

Comment: @JoshyJoseph please make a screenshot(or better just copypaste the code) of the WebWhatsnewView.h and WebWhatsnewView.m

Comment: still same issue please help me

Comment: @JoshyJoseph show us your code from WebWhatsnewView.h and WebWhatsnewView.m please. We can't help if we don't see the problem

Comment: Pls giv me your email id I wil send you the two files.Thanks

Comment: @JoshyJoseph if you can, just post all your code to GitHub or somewhere else. And don't post it in comments please, it is unreadable

Comment: @JoshyJoseph ok, I see the mistake. You added this property to the wrong class. Now it is in WebAboutView, but it has to be in WebWhatsnewView :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a string property/entity in your `WebWhatsnewView`. So that you can set to

```
webwhatsnew.<your_string_entity> = myString;
```

Be sure to synthesize it.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way you can do with Methods. Just declare and define argument type method in WebWhatsnewView Class.

in .h

```
-(void)setSomeData:(NSString*)str;
```

in .m

```
-(void)setSomeData:(NSString*)str
{
  NSString *myString=str;
}
```

Then call it in

```
-(IBAction)Whatsnew {
  NSString *myString =[URL absoluteString]; 
  webwhatsnew = [[WebWhatsnewView alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebWhatsnewView"bundle:nil]; 

  [self.view addSubview:webwhatsnew.view];
  [webwhatsnew setSomeData:myString];

  //or [webwhatsnew setSomeData:@"Here is the real Strings"];
}
```